# How-To Secure Desktop Application To Web Service Calls

Tags: winforms, authentication, web-services

How can i secure Web Service calls from a desktop application (winform) ?

I first think about pass login/password to each web services methods and then check from my database of user is authorized, but i'm looking for a better way to secure that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is written in WCF there are lots of [security scenarios](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurity) already built-in and which can be manipulated as easy as `web.config` settings.